not crazy to take this risk
a. I am not crazy to take this risk.
b. I am not a madman to take this risk.
Do these mean

I am taking this risk and it is not crazy of me to do so

or

Only someone crazy would take this risk and I am not crazy.

?
Many thanks

Neither seems very likely, and I suspect you are misquoting or simplifying without understanding.
There is an idiom "to be crazy about something", which means strongly like something or someone.  "I'm crazy about Taylor Swift." The negation mean "I don't love something, but would probably be understood to be ironic understatement, and mean "I strongly dislike". So "I'm not crazy about taking this risk" would mean literally "I'm unenthusiastic about taking the risk." But would likely to be understood in context to mean "I'm strongly opposed to taking this risk".
However I think you might have omitted the word "enough", which gives a completely different meaning.
On the other hand "I'm crazy enough to take this risk" would mean "I think the risk is so great that taking it might be seen as 'crazy', but I'm going to take the risk anyway."  You could use "mad enough" with a similar meaning, and, of course, the person isn't talking about actual mental illness but is joking.
In the negation, "I'm not crazy enough to take this risk." would mean that "I'm not taking the risk because it would be crazy to do so."  Again, the speaker isn't talking about actual mental health.
Without "enough" or some similar adverb, the sentence don't work.
The construction with "madman" doesn't work well. I suppose you could say "enough of a madman to...", with the same sense.

They mean the second one.  The infinitive clauses modify crazy and madman.
a. I am not [crazy to take this risk].
b. I am not a [madman to take this risk].
The following would be clear to mean the first one:
I take this risk not that I am crazy (or a madman).
Changing the infinitives to ’for’ preposition phrases also gives the first interpretation:
a. I am not crazy for taking this risk.
b. I am not a madman for taking this risk.
